# How do I convert string array element to an integer value?

Tags: android, string, integer

in my Android app I have a set of string array values - tvs[1], tvs[2], tvs3[3], etc., which contain the textview value from a number of Number Pickers.
However, I need the Integer value of each of these strings, so I can then 
multiply this numeric value with the unit cost of various meals. ie 4 x burgers, 3 x chips, etc.
How do I go about this process? I've looked at other questions, but can't find the answer.
Can anyone suggest a solution? ie int Value = .....(tvs[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one of many ways on how to convert a String to int.

```
int a = Integer.valueOf(string);
```

Comment: Thanks - but what is the syntax for using this, say, in a Toast ie using tvs[1]

Comment: This is what I have at the moment: result.append(tvs[1].getText().toString() + "x" + "\nHaddock(Med) 50Rs");  - but I want to multiply the 50Rs by the integer value from the string array element tvs[1]

Comment: total += Integer.valueOf(tvs[1].getText().toString()) * 50

Comment: Hi again! Your answer worked prefectly - one more query (final one!) - how do I add the BigDecimal totalamount1 to totalamount+= , as below.

Comment: BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("4.4");
              BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal (Integer.valueOf(tvs[1].getText().toString()));
              BigDecimal totalamount1 = value.multiply(bd);
              totalamount+= totalamount1;

Comment: Compiler doesn't like it!! But I want to add the result of my arithmetic to the running total..

Comment: It's the line totalamount+= totalamount1 it doesn't like - the += causes a mismatch..

Comment: Are you sure you have big enough numbers to need big decimal? Simple double is more than good enough in most cases. See here how to add stuff to the big decimal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846900/addition-for-bigdecimal

Comment: Ah thanks - so it looks like I just need Double - ie 5 x £4-40, 3 x £1-20 etc.!

Comment: Yes, big decimal is only useful for big numbers as it's name suggests,

Comment: Initialized with: double totalamount=0.0;  and then,   double d1 = 4.4;
              double d2 = Integer.valueOf(tvs[1].getText().toString());
                 totalamount+= d1 * d2; - BUT on using 3 in NumberPicker/TextView, totalamount came out as 0.0 - Any idea why?? Thanks!

Comment: Try Double.valueOf(tvs[1].getText().toString()); ... integer is not for decimal numbers

Comment: Just realised - I was using wrong Number Picker with item in list!!

Comment: Works well now - except result is £13.200000000 - how do I curtail number of decimal places in result?? Many thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065114/how-to-print-a-double-with-two-decimals-in-android

Answer (score 2):

you can simply convert your whole string array to integer array.

```
int[] integersArray = new int[stringArray.length];
for(int i = 0;i < stringArray.length;i++){
   integersArray [i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
}
```