# Format number using decimal format in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, decimalformat

I am facing an issue where I need to do some calculations with a number like for example **5000,00** multiplied it by (**1,025^3**).

So in this case `5000,00 * (1,025^3) = 5385,45`

So my question is, how can I format the number 5385,45 to be like **5.385,45** using decimal format maybe?

I tried by myself and I did this piece of code that outputs 5385,45 in the app but not **5.385,45**

```
    var interestValue = (5000,00*(Math.pow(1.025,yearValue)))
    val number = java.lang.Double.valueOf(interestValue)
    val dec = DecimalFormat("#,00")
    val credits = dec.format(number)
    vValueInterest.text = credits
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a double with two decimals in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065114/how-to-print-a-double-with-two-decimals-in-android)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065163/603270

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is the format you need:

```
val dec = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
```

will print:

```
5.384,45
```

if you need always exactly 2 digits after the decimal point:

```
val dec = DecimalFormat("#,###.00")
```

Comment: 0 will be printed as .00 instead of 0.00. Just use `String.format("%.2f", number)`

Comment: @Choletski `0` will be printed as `0`. The question is not about formatting fixed decimal places but about formatting a number like `5385,45` to `5.385,45`, meaning about the thousands separator.

Comment: If you need `0` to be printed as `0.00`, you can use `DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")`.

Comment: Does `DecimalFormat` work if targeting kotlin-js?

Comment: @Hakanai I only use Kotlin in Android app development so I can't answer your question.

Comment: After some investigation it turns out it does not, but it turns out `String.format` does not either, so they're about as good as each other. :) Still, you can just use `"%,.2f".format(number)` in this case, you get the thousands separator as well (note the `,` in the format string!) I'm still on the lookout for the portable way to do number formatting without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 30):

```
val num = 1.34567
val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING

println(df.format(num))
```

When you run the program, the output will be:
1.34

Check:
https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/round-number-decimal

Answer (score 26):

The "most Kotlin-esque" way I found to do this sort of formatting is:

```kotlin
"%,.2f".format(Locale.GERMAN, 1234.5678)      // => "1.234,57"
"%,.2f".format(Locale.ENGLISH, 1234.5678)     // => "1,234.57"

"%,.2f".format(1234.5678)                     // => "1,234.57" for me, in en_AU
```

Note though that even though this is Kotlin's own extension method on `String`, it still only works on the JVM.

For those looking for a multiplatform implementation (as I was), [mp_stools](https://github.com/sergeych/mp_stools) is one option.

Answer (score 5):

Used:

```
%.numberf

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var A: Double
A = readLine()!!.toDouble()
var bla = A*A
var calculator = 3.14159 * bla
println("A=%.4f".format(calculator))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do something similar but for Kotlin Multiplatform (KMM). I struggled to find a multiplatform solution so I thought I'd post the one I came up with here:

```
// Common
expect fun Double.formatDecimal(maxFractionDigits: Int = 2): String
```

```
// Android
import java.text.DecimalFormat

actual fun Double.formatDecimal(maxFractionDigits: Int): String =
    DecimalFormat().apply {
        isGroupingUsed = false
        minimumFractionDigits = 0
        maximumFractionDigits = maxFractionDigits
        isDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown = false
    }.format(this)
```

```
// iOS
import kotlinx.cinterop.convert
import platform.Foundation.NSNumber
import platform.Foundation.NSNumberFormatter
import platform.Foundation.NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle

actual fun Double.formatDecimal(maxFractionDigits: Int): String =
    NSNumberFormatter().apply {
        minimumFractionDigits = 0u
        maximumFractionDigits = maxFractionDigits.convert()
        numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle
    }.stringFromNumber(number = NSNumber(double = this)) ?: ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `val dec = DecimalFormat("#.###,00")`. For examples of DecimalFormat check this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html).