# php number_format in kotlin

Tags: php, kotlin

I know the [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) function in php. I need something similar in kotlin. I found the java class [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/NumberFormat.html), and it doesn't do what I need. [DecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/text/DecimalFormat) won't do it either.
I also found [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53848189/format-number-using-decimal-format-in-kotlin) about the number format, but it crashes when I use "0+000,00" or "#+###,##" as the format pattern.

I need to format numbers as 275+756,24.

in php I can use `number_format(275756.24,2,",","+")`

Is there a similar function in kotlin?

Greetings from Paraguay.

Claudio Bogado Pompa.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number using decimal format in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53848189/format-number-using-decimal-format-in-kotlin). Also see [the reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/text/DecimalFormat).

Comment: No, it the app crashes when I use "0+000,00" format. It also crashes when I use "#+###,##".

Comment: It appears [this is how you're supposed to do it](https://pl.kotl.in/VN0vjADog). I'm no Kotlin expert though.

Comment: @Jeto Thank you. That code is a mixture of Java and Kotlin. I wrote a Java class with the code you shared, and then converted to Kotlin.

Comment: Ah, didn't know Java classes exposed their get/set methods through Kotlin accessors. Also forgot about optional semicolons. Anyway, glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hoped it was a shorter way.

```
val value = 275756.24
val formatter = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
val symbols = formatter.decimalFormatSymbols
symbols.groupingSeparator = '+'
symbols.decimalSeparator = ','
formatter.decimalFormatSymbols = symbols
val result = formatter.format(value)
```

Thanks Jeto.